# Multivariable asymptotic analysis?

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics

> Show that $k \ln k = \Theta (n)$ implies $k = \Theta (n /\ln n)$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Absolutely nothing. I have no idea how to begin, and don't even totally understand what the question is asking.

Comment: sdf, think of $k$ as a function of $n$.  Perhaps it would help clarify the problem to think of it as asking you to prove that $$k(n) \ln k(n) = \Theta(n) \quad \Rightarrow \quad k(n) = \Theta(n \ln n).$$

Comment: The current statement is false.  Let $$k = \frac{n}{W(n)} = e^{W(n)},$$ where $W$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Then $$k \ln k = W(n) e^{W(n)} = n = \Theta(n)$$ but $$k \sim \frac{n}{\ln n}.
$$  The correct statement, as this counterexample hints, is $$k \ln k = \Theta(n) \quad \Rightarrow \quad k = \Theta\!\left(\frac{n}{\ln n}\right).$$

Comment: @sdf, Now that the problem statement has been cleared up trying to find a proof will no longer be a hopeless endeavor.  I would like to help you with the problem but you should take a crack at it first.  Start by trying to show some basic things, like the fact that $k \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  Next, write out the assumption $k\ln k = \Theta(n)$ as a chain of inequalities.  What does this tell you about $\ln k$?

Comment: In particular, what does it tell you about the relationship between $\ln k$ and $\ln n$?

Answer (score 1):

If $k<\delta n/\ln n$ (where $0<\delta<1$) then $\ln k<\ln \delta+\ln n<2\ln n$. Consequently, 
$$\frac{k\ln k}{n}< \frac{2 k \ln n}{n} <2\delta$$ 
The latter does not happen for very small $\delta$, though.

Comment: The first $\Theta$ in the question can be ignored, the problem follows from the case where $n$ and $f(k)=k \log k$ are equal.  And there one can calculate $f(n / \log n) = n(1 - (\log \log n)/\log n) $ which approximately inverts the function more tightly than the O notation implies.

Comment: (and an upvote in case you were clearing this from the unanswered queue)